# stopping jQuery image zoom running on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I have the `jquery` image zoom library `easyzoom` working successfully on my desktop application.

However I want to shut it down when rendering to all mobile devices including all iPad devices.

What is the best way to achieve that albeit through a media query or modifying the script. Any help or steering would be appreciated.

**index.php**

```
<script>




    var images = document.querySelectorAll(".img-magnifier-container img");
    var image;
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
       image = images[i];
       if(image.complete) {
           magnify(image, 3);
       } else {
            image.addEventListener("load", enableMagnify, false);
       }
    }


    function enableMagnify(e) {
        magnify(e.currentTarget, 2);
    }



</script>
```

**easyzoom.js**

```
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {


var img, glass, w, h, bw;
img = imgID;

/*create magnifier glass:*/
glass = document.createElement("DIV");
glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");

/*insert magnifier glass:*/
img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);

/*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
bw = 3;
w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;

/*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);

/*and also for touch screens:*/
glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);

function moveMagnifier(e) {
  var pos, x, y;
  /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
  e.preventDefault();
  /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
  pos = getCursorPos(e);
  x = pos.x;
  y = pos.y;
  /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
  if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
  if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
  if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
  if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
  /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
  glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";

  /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
  glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
}


function getCursorPos(e) {
  var a, x = 0, y = 0;
  e = e || window.event;
  /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
  a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
  x = e.pageX - a.left;
  y = e.pageY - a.top;
  /*consider any page scrolling:*/
  x = x - window.pageXOffset;
  y = y - window.pageYOffset;
  return {x : x, y : y};
}


} // end of function ///////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this but there might be a better way to do it.

```
let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
if(windowWidth > 1024) {
}
```

Comment: thank you for the idea, I will try this shortly and revert back to you. Incidentally would this be in the easyzoom.js or in my php script

Comment: No worries and I don't know for sure but I'd say inside your php script.